# Hide/Unhide rows button based on color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button that will hide rows within a range if the cell has a specific color, I need it to toggle though back and forth hiding/unhiding the rows with each click. I don't know enough about VBA to fix it.

```
Sub hide_green()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A11:A100")
    For Each MyCell In Rng
        If MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Also is it possible to change the text of the button each click to coordinate with "Hide" "Unhide"?

Comment: you can use filter by color

Comment: @Rosetta I do not know that a filter by color existed. I'm curious to know how to go about it. thx!

Comment: What version Excel do u use? if greater and equal 2007. you could filter by color without needing any VBA code,

Comment: Filter by color only exists with newer versions of Excel.  I believe it was added in 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a second if to see if it's currently hidden or not.

```
Sub hide_green()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim MyCell As Range
Set Rng = Range("A11:A100")
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then
        If MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Liss has a good build on your code, though I would replace the If statements with a Select Case, just so it's cleaner.

```
For Each MyCell In Rng
    If MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden=True Then
        MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden=False
    Else
        Select Case MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex
        Case = 43
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Case <> 43
            MyCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End Select
    End If
Next MyCell
```

Comment: I see what you mean, although not sure how to still utilize an If Else statement in order to unhide the rows on the second click.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to quickly mark what color the rows are (on another column)
[image]

Then just do filtering as usual

[image]

[image]